# Quotes Cutting Off Display Data

Tags: javascript, replace, quotes

I have a multiple column table with one of the columns being a checkbox. I can check different rows and then hit a "Checkout" button and it will display the corresponding selected table row data in the body of an email.

However, I noticed that some of my data contains quotation marks `"` so the data displayed in the email is only the data before the quotes. So for example, if I had the entry `76" bedframe` the only data that would be displayed in the email would be `76`.

How can I fix this?

Here is my javascript code for getting all of the information based on which checkbox is checked. I am mainly concerned about the quotes in the `Description` column:

```
function sendMail() {
    var link = "mailto:me@example.com"
             + "?subject=" + encodeURIComponent("Order")
             + "&body=";

    var body = '';

  $('table tr input[name="check"]:checked').each(function(){
    var current_tr = $(this).parent().parent();

    var data = current_tr.find('.loc').data('loc');
    body +=  encodeURIComponent(data) + '\xa0\xa0';

    var data =current_tr.find('.rp-code').data('rp-code');
    body +=  encodeURIComponent(data) + '\xa0\xa0';

    var data =current_tr.find('.sku').data('sku');
    body +=  encodeURIComponent(data) + '\xa0\xa0';

    var data =current_tr.find('.special-id').data('special-id');
    body +=  encodeURIComponent(data) + '\xa0\xa0';

    var data =current_tr.find('.description').data('description');
    body +=  encodeURIComponent(data) + '\xa0\xa0';

    var data =current_tr.find('.quantity').data('quantity');
    body +=  encodeURIComponent(data) + '\xa0\xa0';

    var data =current_tr.find('.unit').data('unit');
    body +=  encodeURIComponent(data) + '\xa0\xa0';

    var data =current_tr.find('.spinner').data('spinner');
    body +=  encodeURIComponent(data) + '\xa0\xa0';

    body += '%0D%0A';

  });

  body += '';
  link += body;
  console.log(link);

  window.location.href = link;
}
```

HTML:

```
<section id="checkout-btn"> 
<button id="checkout" name="order" onclick="sendMail(); return false">Checkout</button>
</section>    

<br>

<table id="merchTable" cellspacing="5" class="sortable">
    <thead>
        <tr class="ui-widget-header">
            <th class="sorttable_nosort"></th>
            <th class="sorttable_nosort">Loc</th>
            <th class="merchRow">Report Code</th>
            <th class="merchRow">SKU</th>
            <th class="merchRow">Special ID</th>
            <th class="merchRow">Description</th>
            <th class="merchRow">Quantity</th>
            <th class="sorttable_nosort">Unit</th>
            <th style="display: none;" class="num">Quantity #</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

        <?php foreach ($dbh->query($query) as $row) {?>

        <tr>
            <td class="ui-widget-content"><input type="checkbox" class="check" name="check" id="checkid-<?php echo intval ($row['ID'])?>"></td>
            <td class="loc ui-widget-content" data-loc="<?php echo $row['Loc'] ?>"><input type="hidden"><?php echo $row['Loc'];?></td>
            <td name="rows[0][0][rp-code]" class="rp-code ui-widget-content" align="center" data-rp-code="<?php echo $row['Rp-Code'] ?>" id="rp-code-<?php echo intval ($row['Rp-Code'])?>"><?php echo $row['Rp-Code'];?></td>
            <td name="rows[0][0][sku]" class="sku ui-widget-content" data-sku="<?php echo $row['SKU'] ?>" id="sku-<?php echo intval ($row['SKU'])?>"><?php echo $row['SKU'];?></td>
            <td name="rows[0][0][special-id]" class="special-id ui-widget-content" data-special-id="<?php echo $row['Special-ID'] ?>" align="center" id="special-id-<?php echo intval ($row['Special-ID'])?>"><?php echo $row['Special-ID'];?></td>
            <td name="rows[0][0][description]" class="description ui-widget-content" data-description="<?php echo $row['Description'] ?>" id="description-<?php echo intval ($row['Description'])?>"><?php echo $row['Description'];?></td>
            <td name="rows[0][0][quantity]" class="quantity ui-widget-content" data-quantity="<?php echo $row['Quantity'] ?>" align="center" id="quantity-<?php echo intval ($row['Quantity'])?>"><?php echo $row['Quantity'];?></td>
            <td name="rows[0][0][unit]" class="unit ui-widget-content" data-unit="<?php echo $row['Unit'] ?>" id="unit-<?php echo intval ($row['Unit'])?>"><?php echo $row['Unit'];?></td>
            <td name="rows[0][0][quant]" style="display: none;" class="quantity_num ui-widget-content"><input type="textbox" style="width: 100px;" class="spinner" id="spin-<?php echo intval ($row['ID'])?>"></td>
        </tr>

    <?php } ?>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You need to show us your HTML code.

Comment: I think this depends on the email client the user has. I've created this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/e2bozrpp/ – when I click the "send" link, on my machine, an email with body _27" bedframe_ is created as expected. I'm using MS Outlook for Mac v15

Comment: Table cells don’t have a `name` attribute. And when you look at the generated output, you should at least be able to spot what the _problem_ is yourself. `htmlspecialchars` is the answer.

Comment: Yep you're right! `htmlspecialchars` did the trick! Thanks!